# why there is no index merge sort-intersection in mysql index merge optimization?

Tags: mysql

In mysql Index Merge Optimization https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html, i saw three algorithm, they are:

- Index Merge Intersection Access Algorithm
- Index Merge Union Access Algorithm
- Index Merge Sort-Union Access Algorithm

why there is no merge sort-intersection algorithm?

and i have encountered a case where mysql using range instead of index merge.

```
mysql> explain select * from t2 where id>1000 and d<1000;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,idx_d | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 4973 |    10.04 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: [MariaDB added it in 2011](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index_merge-sort_intersection/), so it's possible. You'll have to ask the MySQL developers.

Comment: In the case when one of your indexes to be merged is PRIMARY, there's no benefit to using an index merge. By reading PRIMARY, the row has been examined anyway, so it's cheaper to just apply the second condition.